# Tmi.js how to make bot command take arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, args, twitch

I can't figure out how to make my chatbot take args after commands.

Example: !poll weights [50, 60, 75]

Code:

```
client.on('message', (target, context, msg, self) => {
  if (self) { return; }
  const msgcon = msg.trim();
  if (msgcon.startsWith('!')) {
    if (msgcon === '!poll') {
        client.say(target, '')
        console.log(`* Executed ${msgcon} command at ${target}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`* Unknown command ${msgcon} attempted at ${target}`);
    }
  }
});
```

How do I make it take args?

Answer (score 0):

because the argument type for messsage is just a string you can split it using  the .split method.

```js
const PREFIX = "!";
let [command, ...args] = message.slice(PREFIX.length).split(/ +/g); 

if (command == "!test") {
 console.log({ command, args })
}
```

if the user where to say write in chat `!test one two three` it would output:

```json
{
  command: "!test",
  args: ["one", "two", "three"]
}
```

meaning you can access each argument by typing `args[x]` (remember that javascript counts from 0)

---

**Explanation**: essentially what I'm doing is getting the message which is type string and using the .slice method to remove the prefix (cleaner command value) and then splitting the message for every space in the string putting it into a array. the first item in the array will be set as the command while the rest are the arguments.

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice